# Method Illuminate\Support\Collection::save does not exist

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I want to create update function, but the error keep shown. Is it because of the join query or the get() or first() method. I dont know how to solve this.

```
Method Illuminate\Support\Collection::save does not exist.
```

**Controller:**

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {


        // dd($request);

        $request->validate([
            'first_name'                        => 'max:150',
            'last_name'                         => 'max:150',

            'userD_ic'                          => 'max:12',
            'userD_position'                    => 'max:50',
            'userD_epf'                         => 'max:20',
            'userD_socso'                       => 'max:20',
            'userD_passport'                    => 'max:30',

            'user_id'                           => 'numeric',
            'ea_serial_no'                      => 'required|numeric',
            'ea_employer_id'                    => 'required|numeric',
            'ea_employee_income_tax_no'         => 'required|numeric',
            'ea_lhdn_branch'                    => 'required|max:255',

        ]);

        $eaforms = DB::table('ea')
            ->join('users', 'ea.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
            ->join('user_details', 'ea.user_id', '=', 'user_details.user_id')
            ->where('ea.id', $id)
            ->select('ea.*', 'users.first_name', 'users.last_name', 'user_details.userD_position', 'user_details.userD_ic', 'user_details.userD_passport', 'user_details.userD_epf', 'user_details.userD_socso')
            ->get();

        $eaforms->first_name                        = $request->first_name;
        $eaforms->last_name                         = $request->last_name;

        $eaforms->userD_ic                          = $request->userD_ic;
        $eaforms->userD_position                    = $request->userD_position;
        $eaforms->userD_epf                         = $request->userD_epf;
        $eaforms->userD_socso                       = $request->userD_socso;
        $eaforms->userD_passport                    = $request->userD_passport;

        $eaforms->user_id                           = $request->user_id;
        $eaforms->ea_serial_no                      = $request->ea_serial_no;
        $eaforms->ea_employer_id                    = $request->ea_employer_id;
        $eaforms->ea_employee_income_tax_no         = $request->ea_employee_income_tax_no;
        $eaforms->ea_lhdn_branch                    = $request->ea_lhdn_branch;

        $eaforms->save();

        return redirect()->route('ea.view', $eaforms->id)->with('update', 'add');
    }
```

**Model:**

```
    class EaForms extends Model
{

    protected $table = 'ea';

    use HasFactory, SoftDeletes;

    protected $fillable = [
        'user_id',
        'ea_year',
        'ea_serial_no',
        'ea_employer_id',
        'ea_employee_income_tax_no',
        'ea_lhdn_branch',
        'created_at',
        'updated_at',
        'deleted_at',

    ];

    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
}
```

Comment: Take a look here: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#updating-belongs-to-relationships

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this (With your relationship method called users)

```
$eaforms = EaForms::where('id',$id)->first();
    // Update user data
    $eaforms->first_name                               = $request->first_name;
    $eaforms->last_name                                = $request->last_name;
    $eaforms->userD_ic                                 = $request->userD_ic;
    $eaforms->userD_position                           = $request->userD_position;
    $eaforms->userD_epf                                = $request->userD_epf;
    $eaforms->userD_socso                              = $request->userD_socso;
    $eaforms->userD_passport                           = $request->userD_passport;
    // Update EA Forms
    $eaforms->users->user_id                           = $request->user_id;
    $eaforms->users->ea_serial_no                      = $request->ea_serial_no;
    $eaforms->users->ea_employer_id                    = $request->ea_employer_id;
    $eaforms->users->ea_employee_income_tax_no         = $request->ea_employee_income_tax_no;
    $eaforms->users->ea_lhdn_branch                    = $request->ea_lhdn_branch;

    $eaforms->users->save();
    $eaforms->save();
```

Comment: @farahain97 Why are you not using Relationships? You will never get `users` populated because you are doing a manual join.....